# Identifying outliers in lme4 models

Tags: r, time-series, lme4, mixed-models, outliers

I want to identify outliers in lmer models (**lme4** package). I'm **not** interested in removing them (what the **LMERConvenienceFunctions** package does) - I simply want to see the outliers listed.

An example of a model I use:

```
model1<-lmer(Value~ Moisture + Planting + (day|plot), data=plants1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define outliers in the same way that `LMERConvenienceFunctions` does (standardized level 1 residuals > 2.5SD from 0) then this will work:

```
res1 <- resid(model1, type = "pearson") # Extract standardized residuals
plants1[which(abs(res1) > 2.5),] # Get the rows which absolute residuals > 2.5
```

if you have missing data in `plants1` make sure to set `na.action = 'na.exclude'` in the `lmer` command before extracting the residuals. This will ensure that observations with missing data are set to `NA` instead of omitting them.